# Does friendly fire off apply to incendiaries?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Personally, I love playing with FF. But on most public servers where I live it is off.

I was wondering if that applies to molotovs and such?

With FF off, can I throw a molotov into a choke point and then have my teammates run through unscathed? If yes, that seems like a really slick tactical trick...

Comment: Competitive games aren't balanced for casual play. So even if it works, no one really cares, because it's still a trick that only works in a mode where people aren't playing to win.

Comment: Yes, if FF is off then molotoff does not cause damage. Well usually choke points are burned from both sides, just to be sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when friendly fire is off incendiaries will not cause damage to your teammates. Yes this can be abused by players who are coordinating well enough.

In ye olde CS and CS: Source, a number of tactics on non-FF servers would crop up that took advantage of this. My favorite was placing one or two people at a door and then having the rest of the team nuke the area with grenades. The people at the door would then immediately breach while the grenades were going off. There was a pretty good chance you would catch the opposing team in mid-retreat, and the additional force from the breaching players would usually lock down the spot.

This isn't a big deal though, since non-FF servers are more for casual play. Nobody playing competitively would be on these servers anyway.

Comment: Not true.  ESEA servers have FF off.  Those are quite competitive.

Comment: Not necessarily though, it doesn't represent the majority of competitive servers.  Most comp servers have FF on.